# ImageView floating in center of CardView

Tags: java, android, xml

I want a simple card based layout with the image at the top of the card. However whenever I add this, the image floats in the vertical center of the card. How can I force the image to the top of the card without any hacks such as setting negative margins?

The XML I am using is here

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#EEE">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/edinburgh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="@id/card_view" ></ImageView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And here's a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Change `android:layout_alignParentTop="@id/card_view"` to `android:layout_gravity="top"`

**Explanation:**

1. `android:layout_alignParentTop="@id/card_view"` value must be boolean, not View's id
2. `android:layout_alignParentTop` is attribute for `RelativeLayout` children, where `CardView` inherits from `FrameLayout`, not `RelativeLayout`.